# Automatically delete items X days old from trash (ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu

Is there a way to either make ubuntu cap the trash bin at a certain size, or automatically remove items that are 30 days+ old out of the trash bin automatically? If not, does anyone know of a script anywhere that does this?

Edit: Is this even possible? It doesn't seem like the modification date of a file is even changed when it's moved to the trash.

Answer (score 1):

you can use find in a cron job

```
find /path/to/.Junk/ -type f -mtime +30 -delete >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I should add that I use this to remove junk mail from a folder. I don't know if it would work the same for the system's trash bin.

Comment: The modified date doesn't seem to change when a file is moved to the trash.

Comment: Handling folders would be a good addition to this, though they complicate it somewhat. You don't want to remove old folders with new things inside.

Comment: I don't know that this is an ideal solution, even if it does work, but just for fun... 
what about -atime +30?

Comment: @blahdiblah, this would leave the folders in place and only handle the files in the subfolders ("-type f"). I imagine a second pass aimed at looking for empty folders would do the trick, though.